# PHP Error Arguments Not an Array Error

Tags: php, arrays, arguments

HI my code isn't working and I get this error when the code is run:

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0b6Z.jpg)

This is line 110 of the code:

```
$results = array_merge($results, $game_list[$row][$col]);
```

And this is the rest of the code:

```
$results = array();

        for ($row = 0; $row < $num_rows; $row++){

                            if (strstr($game_list[$row][2], $search) or strstr($game_list[$row][3], $search)){
                                   for ($col = 0; $col < count($game_list[$row]); $col ++) { 

                                           $results = array_merge($results, $game_list[$row][$col]);




                                           $successful = true;
                                   }
                            }


        }
                    if ($successful == true){
                            echo "<table>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Game ID</th>
                                    <th>Genre</th>
                                    <th>Game Name</th>
                                    <th>Game Description</th>
                                    <th>Rental Cost Per Day</th>
                                </tr>";

                                // Set number of table rows
                                $num_rows = count($results) - 1;
                                // Set number of table columns
                                $num_cols = 5;

                                // Start loop to generate rows
                                for($row = 0; $row < $num_rows; $row++) {
                                    // Generate row HTML
                                    echo "<tr>";

                                    //Start loop to generate columns (nested FOR loop!)
                                    for($col = 0 ; $col < $num_cols; $col++) {
                                            // Generate column HTML
                                            echo "<td>". $results[$row][$col] ."</td>";
                                    }
                                // End of columns loop
                                // Generate end of row HTML
                                echo "</tr>";
                                }

                            echo "</table>";
```

The code is meant to search through the array game_list and see if a keyword a user has entered is in the array. If it is, then the code will take the whole row in the array game_list and add it to the array results. This array will then be displayed in a table to the user.

If anyone can give me a fix that would be great.

Comment: well, `$game_list[$row][$col]` is a string, not an array. Why don't you simply do: `$result[] = $game_list[$row];`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that error is, that you try to merge an array with a string,
`array_merge` takes two arrays as arguments.

I'd suggest not to use `array_merge()` at all, but simply add the requested data to the results array:

```
<?php
$results = Array();
...
   $results[] = $game_list[$row];
...
?>
```

Comment: Because when I do this I get the error: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading on line 110

Comment: I don't beleive you used the (exact) code I've shown here, cause there's nothing that *reads' `$results[]`. Only possibility could be, that `$row` is undefined, but still I think it would throw a different error then.